# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent - Accessor through Scope

Tags: laravel, scope, eloquent, accessor

I have a model which I need to check values on and return back an unhealthy status. I have created an Accessor, which is working and returns true or false as expected.

```
$task->unhealthy()
```

Accessor code

```
    public function getUnhealthyAttribute(){

        //Is in Active status
        if ( $this->status_id == 1 ){
            return true;
        }

        //Has overdue items
        if ( $this->items()->overdue()->count() > 0 ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I now have a requirement to retrieve a collection of all "unhealthy" Tasks.

**Question**: Is it possible to leverage my Accessor with a scope? What would be the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [collection's `filter()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-filter) to filter only the *unhealthy* tasks once you have a collection with *all* the tasks:

```php
$unhealthy_tasks = $tasks->filter(function($task, $key) {
    return $task->unhealthy; // if returns true, will be in $unhealthy_tasks
});
```